# Element with position absolute affects container height when using translateY

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how is it possible that an absolute element could affect container height when translateY is used. I did minimal reproduction in the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-leaf-3hqsjm?file=/src/styles.css

CSS:

```
.section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: right;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div className="section">
  <div className="content">
    <div>Test test</div>
    <div>Test test</div>
    <div>Test test</div>
  </div>
  <div className="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve it? I would like to use translateY for animation appearance.

Comment: It's working 100% as expected. you are positioning an element out of the html flow, so the height of your section is not changing... and you get the scroll bar to help you reach it. It's not a translateY problem. do not use translate and add a negative bottom value and the same will happen.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want scroll add `display: contents;` to `bottom` class.
[here's](https://codesandbox.io/embed/peaceful-carson-tj5fwx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) your code for example.